# löve2d #array not returning last integer index of an array

Tags: lua, love2d

Vanilla Lua code (new empty project):

```
local array = {1,2,3,4,5}
array[3] = nil
array[4] = nil
print(#array) -- returns 5
```

Löve2d code (new empty project):

```
function love.load()
    local array = {1,2,3,4,5}
    array[3] = nil
    array[4] = nil
    print(#array) -- returns 2 (bug?)
end
```

Is it how it should work or is it a bug?

Lua wiki says: The # operator doesn't count all the items in the table (!). Instead it finds the last integer (non-fractional number) key.

So I think it is a bug but I'm not sure as I am fairly new to Lua and Löve2d.

I was about to report this possible bug on the project's website but I wanted to make sure it was a bug first.

Comment: If your array has `nil`s inside, `#` is not defined on it (and `#` may return any garbage).  Lua wiki is wrong.

Comment: If in love2d i set only 1 value to nil, it also returns 5, so what is going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation on The Length Operator `#`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.5):

> The length operator is denoted by the unary operator #. The length of
>   a string is its number of bytes (that is, the usual meaning of string
>   length when each character is one byte).
>
> The length of a table t is defined to be any integer index n such that
>   t[n] is not nil and t[n+1] is nil; moreover, if t[1] is nil, n can be
>   zero. For a regular array, with non-nil values from 1 to a given n,
>   its length is exactly that n, the index of its last value. **If the
>   array has "holes" (that is, nil values between other non-nil values),
>   then #t can be any of the indices that directly precedes a nil value
>   (that is, it may consider any such nil value as the end of the array)**.

Emphasis mine. It seems that is how it is designed. **Any** `nil` can be considered the end of the array. As sloppy as that seems, it appears to be *on purpose*.

As for seeing differences in test results, it could be related to running different versions. Check to ensure you are testing using the same version for each of your tests.

Comment: What seems weird to me is that love2d does not return the same result as lua even though it is the same code.

Comment: What versions are being used in both instances. Have you ensured the same version in both tests?

Comment: What I was trying to achieve was to 'compress' an array, i wanted to remove multiple elements by setting them to nil, and then reorder the table, But I'm kinda lost know, is there any way to get the last index other than iterating with the 'pairs' function and get the highest key/index?

Comment: That should probably be a new question, and would probably have a much better chance of getting a good answer that way. Not to mention, it would be better for other users who might be looking for that same solution.

Comment: It's not the same version, 5.1 and 5.3, that's probably why. I didn't think about that.

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much.